# When creating loader for hashmap, my bucket points back to itself

Tags: c, hashmap

I am learning C and debugging code for spell checking a chosen text file. My last hurdle here is the load function of my hashmap. It successfully reads a given word from a dictionary file, stores it, assigns it to a temp `node *`, but the problem comes when I try to make my struct `node *table[] = tmp`;

Any thoughts? Also my hash function is working, and is not the problem. Thank you all.

**Edit:** it seems as if the `table->next` doesn't update to a pointer to the next item in the singly linked list. When I try to do `new_word->next = table[index];` it doesn't change the address and stays as `0x00`.

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open up file to read dictionary to
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening dictionary file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // create variable to store the current word in
    char *current_word = malloc(LENGTH * (sizeof(char)));
    if (current_word == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in allocating memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // initialize index for finding hash index, and count, to store word count
    int index;
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(current_word, LENGTH, dict) != NULL)
    {
        //open up a node to store the current new word in, also store current word
        node *new_word = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_word == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // copy word to new world variable, store next pointer in variable as well,
        // set as new head of table listy
        strcpy(new_word->word, current_word);
        index = hash(new_word->word);
        new_word->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new_word;
        free(new_word);

        count++;
    }
```

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(char)` will always be `1`. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof#Notes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is silly: you free the node with `free(new_word)` after you link it into the hash table.  Just remove this call.

Note also these remarks:

- there is no need to allocate the `current_word` array. Just define it as a local object with automatic storage.
- remember to close the file in case of error to avoid ressource leakage.
- it is somewhat confusing to return `true` (ie: 1) in case of error.  A more consistent API would be to return the number of words successfully read and `-1` in case of error.
- you should strip the trailing newline stored by `fgets()` in `current_word`.
- do not comment the obvious.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 80
#define HASH_TABLE_LENGTH 1023

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char word[LENGTH];
} node;

extern int hash(const char *s); // returns a positive value < HASH_TABLE_LENGTH

node *table[HASH_TABLE_LENGTH];

int load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open dictionary file %s: %s\n",
                dictionary, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    char current_word[LENGTH];

    int index;
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(current_word, LENGTH, dict) != NULL)
    {
        node *new_word = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_word == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory.\n");
            fclose(dict);
            return -1;
        }
        // strip the trailing newline if any
        current_word[strcspn(current_word, "\n")] = '\0';
        strcpy(new_word->word, current_word);
        // link the new word at the head of the hash table slot list
        index = hash(new_word->word);
        new_word->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new_word;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return count;
}

// For illustration, here is the code to free the hash table:
void free_hash_table(void) {
    for (int index = 0; i < HASH_TABLE_LENGTH; i++) {
        while (table[index] != NULL) {
            node *p = table[index];
            table[index] = p->next;
            free(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh as table = new_word. Then i assume when deleting table new word will be freed as well?

Comment: @CharlieWebster: `new_word` is a pointer. You copy the pointer to `table[index]`.  Both point to the same allocated object.  Then `new_word` goes out of scope when the next iteration of the `while` loop occurs but the hash table now *owns* the object.  This is a classic idiom in C.  These nodes will be freed when you discard the hash table, using 2 nested loops.